# Anybody know how to do an Asynchronous creation of tables using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Table?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, smo

I currently have a problem with the datareader when creating Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Table asynchronously. Note: I derived my SmoTable from TableView and IDisposable.

```
  private async Task Generate()  
  {
       await Task.Run(()=>
       {
          MSSMSDatabase db = CreateDB(txtDBname.Text);
          List<string> tableNames = GetTableNameList();
          for(string tableName in tableNames)
          {
              using(SmoTable tbl = new Table(db, tableName)) // <=== after a few loops, the error occurs within here.
              {
                  foreach(var col in columnList)
                  {
                      tbl.AddColumns(col); 
                  }
                  tbl.Create();          
              }
          }

       });
   }
```

Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

I tried implementing IDisposable to my SmoTable class that I derived from the TableView class but still have the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a trial and error and found out that you need to create a new connection for each table creation to create a separate datareader for it. So, if you include the instantiation of Server in the foreach loop it will create a new connection and hence a new datareader.

```
for(string tableName in tableNames)
{
    using(SmoTable tbl = new Table(db, tableName)) // <=== after a few loops, the error occurs within here.
    {
        foreach(var col in columnList)
        {
            _server = GetSQLServer(); // <=== this is basically Server server = new Server(); return server; kind of method.
            db = _server.Databases[_databaseName];
            tbl.AddColumns(col); 
        }
        tbl.Create();          
    }
}
```